# rxjs forkJoin never completes

Tags: rxjs

This forkJoin never completes, even though the observables within it do, what am I missing?

```
return Observable.forkJoin([
  this.ProductManager.get(params['brandId'], params['productId'])
    .map(product => <Product> product)
    .do(product => {this.product = product;})
    .do(() => console.log('a1'), () => console.log('a2'), () => console.log('a3')),

  this.basketContext.basket.take(1)
    .do(() => console.log('b1'), () => console.log('b2'), () => console.log('b3'))
])
.do(() => console.log('1'), () => console.log('2'), () => console.log('3'));
```

Console:

```
b1
b3
a1
a3
1
```

Why is the onComplete for the forkJoin never called?

Comment: Are you sure all source Observables emit at least one item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, if the subsequent subscribe() throws an error, the complete callback never finished... The error was silent so I mistook it for the forkJoin not completing.